# Are good writers are good theoreticans?

Tags: writing

I am Ph.D student works in theoretical computer science (algebra). I will be graduating next year. I have been able to publish 2 paper currently writing a paper. Idea's are comming into my mind these days, and also I start writing as soon as possible. I try to write the things as early as possible. The problem from which I am suffering most is "writing skill", as the feedback I have from my collegue I have good idea's but writing is not that much good even after two months of writing ( I have written many drafts). Note that in those two months in which I were writing the draft of the paper, I was also working on some other problems.

I know that my writing is not great, but I have heard that good writers are good theoreticians. I may have very good idea but I may not be that much good writer and due to this thing I may not be much successful, Please help

Question : Are good writers are good theoreticians?

Comment: I just can’t see correlation much less causation here...

Comment: I see no reason to believe that good writers are good theoreticians, or the other way around. But it is probably true that most *successful* good theoreticians are also good writers because writing well is necessary to ensure that others want to read your publications.

Comment: Every university I know of has a writing center. Have you tried to use their services?

Comment: There's probably a relationship between clear thinking and clear writing (mostly in that direction), but clear writing can still be dry and dull, and clear thinking doesn't necessarily produce original insights.

Comment: I can't opine on whether this is true, but I am wondering where you heard it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you started studying computer science, has anyone spent significant time teaching you how to write? Of your whole time learning, what proportion was spent learning computer science, and what proportion spent learning writing skills?

If your answers to these questions are what I expect them to be, then you need to put time into learning to write. It is a skill, not a gift. It can be taught, and it can be learnt. (I should know. I spent five years studying pure mathematics at undergraduate and postgraduate level without ever writing more than about three consecutive words. When I first attempted to enter my chosen profession, which required a written examination, I failed.) I subsequently put a lot of effort into learning how to write. People in my profession, which is very much based on use of words, tell me that my writing is very good.

For me, the career enhancing book was Barbara Minto's "The Pyramid Principle" that makes the case that clarity of thought leads to clarity of thinking. The logical approach she takes appealed to me as a mathematician, and maybe that might appeal to you as a computer scientist. But there are lots of books.

I suggest it is not helpful to comfort yourself with such thoughts as 'good theoreticians are never good writers, and vice versa'. If you are bright enough to be good at computer science then you are bright enough to learn how to be a competent writer.

Answer (score -1):

**Not necessarily**.

Case in point: JK Rowling is a world-renowned writer, but I don't know anyone who has called her a good theoretician.

Comment: This is called being too literal-minded.